# Grails Logging - Only log my application, not grails specific junk

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

Starting from the default logging config, I added the root{} block to turn on debug level logging.  And I added a method for my controllers...

```
log4j = {
  error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
      'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
      'org.springframework',
      'org.hibernate',
      'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

  warn 'org.mortbay.log'
  debug 'grails.app.controller'

  root {
    debug()
  }
}
```

And now I get debug alright. But I get it from everywhere.  All the startup junk that Grails goes through when doing a run-app, clearing cache, loading spring beans, etc.  I want to configure this so the only logging I get is from *my* code.  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Config.groovy file, in a log4j section, define a log appender  like this:

```
 appender name: "appLog",
        new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(
        threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO,
        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd", 
        file: "${logDirectory}/app.log", 
        layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '[%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS}] %p %c{5} %m%n'))
```

Let the root logger be the root, and log on the console:

```
root {
  additivity = true
  info stdout
}
```

And then add debug only to your app in a specific logger

```
debug additivity:true, appLog: "grails.app"
```

The grails [Logging Section](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging) has been changing a lot, but is pretty much up to date now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Although I'm not sure this is transparent enough in the documentation.  I've been reading it all day. :)  Thanks for the answer.